# C# Checkers Game Movement

Tags: c#

I am trying to get basic movement working in my C# checkers game i.e. by moving one space diagonally by having a process where you select the button's counter you want to move then select the button you want to move to, but I can't seem to get it working. Here is my code

I have a 2nd form for logging in but it works fine, main issues is just movement so ignore small section of code that talks about `F2` or `form2`.

This is Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Checkers
{
    public partial class Board : Form
    {
        bool turn = true; // true = blue turn, false = red turn
        //Player currentPlayer; an alternative
        int turncount = 0;
        static String player1initial;
        static String player2initial;
        Player p1 = new Player();
        Player p2 = new Player();
        Grid[,] buttons = new Grid[8, 8];        

        private Grid selectedbutton;
        private Grid MoveTobutton;

        private char PlayerMark = 'b';

        public Board()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoginForm F2 = new LoginForm();
            F2.ShowDialog();
            P1NameLabel.Text = player1initial;
            P2NameLabel.Text = player2initial;
            p1.GetPlayerName = player1initial;
            p2.GetPlayerName = player2initial;
            p1.GetPlayerWinCount = 0;
            p2.GetPlayerWinCount = 0;

        }

        public static void SetNames(String n1, String n2)
        {
            player1initial = n1;
            player2initial = n2;
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }        

        private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttons[0, 0] = new Grid(A1, 'b',1);
            buttons[0, 1] = new Grid(B1, ' ',2);
            buttons[0, 2] = new Grid(C1, 'b',3);
            buttons[0, 3] = new Grid(D1, ' ', 4);
            buttons[0, 4] = new Grid(E1, 'b', 5);
            buttons[0, 5] = new Grid(F1, ' ', 6);
            buttons[0, 6] = new Grid(G1, 'b', 7);
            buttons[0, 7] = new Grid(H1, ' ', 8);
            buttons[1, 0] = new Grid(A2, ' ',9);
            buttons[1, 1] = new Grid(B2, 'b',10);
            buttons[1, 2] = new Grid(C2, ' ',11);
            buttons[1, 3] = new Grid(D2, 'b', 12);
            buttons[1, 4] = new Grid(E2, ' ', 13);
            buttons[1, 5] = new Grid(F2, 'b', 14);
            buttons[1, 6] = new Grid(G2, ' ', 15);
            buttons[1, 7] = new Grid(H2, 'b', 16);
            buttons[2, 0] = new Grid(A3, 'b',17);
            buttons[2, 1] = new Grid(B3, ' ',18);
            buttons[2, 2] = new Grid(C3, 'b',19);
            buttons[2, 3] = new Grid(D3, ' ', 20);
            buttons[2, 4] = new Grid(E3, 'b', 21);
            buttons[2, 5] = new Grid(F3, ' ', 22);
            buttons[2, 6] = new Grid(G3, 'b', 23);
            buttons[2, 7] = new Grid(H3, ' ', 24);
            buttons[3, 0] = new Grid(A4, ' ', 25);
            buttons[3, 1] = new Grid(B4, ' ', 26);
            buttons[3, 2] = new Grid(C4, ' ', 27);
            buttons[3, 3] = new Grid(D4, ' ', 28);
            buttons[3, 4] = new Grid(E4, ' ', 29);
            buttons[3, 5] = new Grid(F4, ' ', 30);
            buttons[3, 6] = new Grid(G4, ' ', 31);
            buttons[3, 7] = new Grid(H4, ' ', 32);
            buttons[4, 0] = new Grid(A5, ' ', 33);
            buttons[4, 1] = new Grid(B5, ' ', 34);
            buttons[4, 2] = new Grid(C5, ' ', 35);
            buttons[4, 3] = new Grid(D5, ' ', 36);
            buttons[4, 4] = new Grid(E5, ' ', 37);
            buttons[4, 5] = new Grid(F5, ' ', 38);
            buttons[4, 6] = new Grid(G5, ' ', 39);
            buttons[4, 7] = new Grid(H5, ' ', 40);
            buttons[5, 0] = new Grid(A6, ' ', 41);
            buttons[5, 1] = new Grid(B6, 'r', 42);
            buttons[5, 2] = new Grid(C6, ' ', 43);
            buttons[5, 3] = new Grid(D6, 'r', 44);
            buttons[5, 4] = new Grid(E6, ' ', 45);
            buttons[5, 5] = new Grid(F6, 'r', 46);
            buttons[5, 6] = new Grid(G6, ' ', 47);
            buttons[5, 7] = new Grid(H6, 'r', 48);
            buttons[6, 0] = new Grid(A7, 'r', 49);
            buttons[6, 1] = new Grid(B7, ' ', 50);
            buttons[6, 2] = new Grid(C7, 'r', 51);
            buttons[6, 3] = new Grid(D7, ' ', 52);
            buttons[6, 4] = new Grid(E7, 'r', 53);
            buttons[6, 5] = new Grid(F7, ' ', 54);
            buttons[6, 6] = new Grid(G7, 'r', 55);
            buttons[6, 7] = new Grid(H7, ' ', 56);
            buttons[7, 0] = new Grid(A8, ' ', 57);
            buttons[7, 1] = new Grid(B8, 'r', 58);
            buttons[7, 2] = new Grid(C8, ' ', 59);
            buttons[7, 3] = new Grid(D8, 'r', 60);
            buttons[7, 4] = new Grid(E8, ' ', 61);
            buttons[7, 5] = new Grid(F8, 'r', 62);
            buttons[7, 6] = new Grid(G8, ' ', 63);
            buttons[7, 7] = new Grid(H8, 'r', 64);

            FillGrid();
            Start.Hide();
            checkcurrentplayer();
        }

        private void FillGrid()
        {
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                    {
                        buttons[i, j].GetButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(Button_Click);

                        if (buttons[i, j].getmark == 'r')
                        {
                            buttons[i, j].GetButton.Image = Checkers.Properties.Resources.red;
                        }

                        else if (buttons[i, j].getmark == 'b')
                        {
                            buttons[i, j].GetButton.Image = Checkers.Properties.Resources.blue;
                        }
                        else if (buttons[i, j].GetButton.BackColor == Color.Black)
                        {
                            buttons[i, j].GetButton.Enabled = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            buttons[i, j].GetButton.Image = null;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: please click 'X' in Program Window and exit.");
            }
        }

        private void CheckForWinner()
        {
            bool winner = false;
            String winnertext = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                {
                    if (buttons[i, j].GetButton.Image == Checkers.Properties.Resources.blue)
                    {
                        if (turn == true)
                        {
                            disablebuttons();
                            winnertext = (p1.GetPlayerName);
                            p1.GetPlayerWinCount += 1;
                            winner = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (buttons[i, j].GetButton.Image == Checkers.Properties.Resources.red)
                    {
                        if (turn == false)
                        {
                            disablebuttons();
                            winnertext = (p2.GetPlayerName);
                            p2.GetPlayerWinCount += 1;
                            winner = true;
                        }
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show(winnertext + " Wins!");
                }
            }
        }

        private void disablebuttons()
        {
            foreach (Control c in Controls)
            {
                if (c.GetType() == typeof(Button))
                {
                    Button b = (Button)c;
                    b.Enabled = false;
                }

            }// end foreach
        }

        private void newGameToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            turn = true;

            foreach (Control c in Controls)
            {
                try
                {
                    Button b = (Button)c;
                    b.Enabled = true;
                    b.Image = null;
                    FillGrid();
                }
                catch { }

            }// end foreach
        }

        private void checkcurrentplayer()
        {
            if (turn == true)
            {
                currentplayerlabel.Text = ("Current Player: " + p1.GetPlayerName);
            }
            else
            {
                currentplayerlabel.Text = ("Current Player: " + p2.GetPlayerName);
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button currentbtn = (Button)sender;
            checkcurrentplayer();

            if (selectedbutton != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                    {
                        if (currentbtn.Image == buttons[i, j].GetButton.Image)
                        {
                            if (buttons[i, j].GetButton.Image == null)
                            {
                                MoveTobutton = buttons[i, j];
                                MoveTobutton.GetButton.Image = selectedbutton.GetButton.Image;
                                selectedbutton.GetButton.Image = null;
                                selectedbutton = null;
                                turn = !turn;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                    {
                        if (currentbtn.Image == buttons[i, j].GetButton.Image)
                        {
                            if (turn == true)
                            {
                                if (buttons[i, j].GetButton.Image == Checkers.Properties.Resources.blue)
                                {
                                    selectedbutton = buttons[i, j];
                                }
                            }
                            else if (turn == false)
                            {
                                if (buttons[i, j].GetButton.Image == Checkers.Properties.Resources.red)
                                {
                                    selectedbutton = buttons[i, j];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code to my Grid Class

```
namespace Checkers
{
    public class Grid
    {
        private Button button;
        private char Mark;
        private int location;

        public Grid(Button _button, char _mark, int _location)
        {
            button = _button;
            Mark = _mark;
            location = _location;
        }

        public Button GetButton
        {
            get { return button; }
            set { button = value; }
        }

        public char getmark
        {
            get { return Mark; }
            set { Mark = value; }
        }

        public int getlocation
        {
            get { return location; }
            set { location = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Picture of gameboard itself and picture of gameboard after start button has been clicked, after grid is filled start button is hidden.]

[image: Picture of Gameboard itself]

Here is code for a basic no validation solution (Reference for anyone else making c# checkers program) That should work perfectly fine.

```
    private void Mouse_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Button currentbutton = (Button)sender;

        if (selectedbutton != null)
        {
            MoveTobutton = currentbutton;
            Image currentimage = selectedbutton.Image;
            selectedbutton.Image = MoveTobutton.Image;
            MoveTobutton.Image = currentimage;
            selectedbutton = null;
        }
        else
        {
            selectedbutton = currentbutton;

        }
    }
```

Comment: What does “I can't seem to get it working” mean? It throws an exception? Tell us the exception. It doesn't do what you expected? What does it do? What did you expect?

Comment: When i click a button with a counter then another button it does nothing.

Comment: I'm gonna try and add a photo of the board after start game has been clicked.

Comment: I have a photo of the board before start game button is clicked and photo after start button is clicked. the start button is hidden after it is clicked. Sorry for order I am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: You'll need to learn how to [use a debugger](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), but `currentbtn.Image == buttons[i, j].GetButton.Image` does a reference comparison and I suspect you want a value comparison. In fact, you should not be trying to compare images at all. Create a model of the board and draw a representation of the model on-screen when required; do not try to use the UI to do logic.

Comment: You should learn to approach problem-solving and help-seeking differently. When something doesn't work, attempt to reproduce the issue in a simpler context. E.g. write a whole new program that has _only_ the logic you are having trouble with, using the _smallest_ amount of data and objects possible (i.e. not an 8x8 board). Often, you'll be able to solve the problem yourself. But if not, then you have a proper [mcve] to share with others when you want to ask your question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I was able to get the movement working by making a new program with a 3x3 grid and working with that until I got movement working. I had to remove my validation measure in the button click event in the main program for it to work but now that basic movement works the validation should be easy to reimplement.

Comment: If you found a solution that would be useful to others, post it to the Answer box below. After a day or so you can accept your own answer, and you'll get a participation badge as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void Mouse_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Button currentbutton = (Button)sender;

    if (selectedbutton != null)
    {
        MoveTobutton = currentbutton;
        Image currentimage = selectedbutton.Image;
        selectedbutton.Image = MoveTobutton.Image;
        MoveTobutton.Image = currentimage;
        selectedbutton = null;
    }
    else
    {
        selectedbutton = currentbutton;

    }
}
```